# SQL Query convert to LINQ

Tags: sql-to-linq-conversion

I have SQL Query

```
SELECT project_id,count(project_id) as vote_count from Votesgroup by project_id;
```

And how i can write this with LINQ? My LINQ starting code:

```
 private int GetCountOfVotes()
    {
        using (var db = new SafetyFundDbContext(Options))
        {

            return db.Votes.Select()

        }          
    }
```

Sorry, Yes I know question is so stupid, but Im newbie :D .

Comment: This seems similar to this question (minus the WHERE clause): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581089/convert-sql-into-linq-query

Comment: Thanks for your attention! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't vote and mark as correct answer.

```
foreach(var vote in  db.Votes.GroupBy(vot => vot.project_id)
                    .Select(group => new { 
                         ProjectID = group.Key, 
                         Count = group.Count() 
                    })
                    .OrderBy(x => x.ProjectID)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", vote.ProjectID, vote.Count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help! ")